# What ImageFormat should I use?

Tags: android

I'm getting image with

```
Graphics graphics = game.getGraphics();
Images.menu = graphics.newImage("image.png", ImageFormat.RGB565);
```

but the picture doesn't look good. You can see transitions if picture have gradient.
Except RGB565, there is also ARGB4444 and ARGB8888, but they are even worse than RGB565.

Is there any way that the image look the way it actually looks in folder Images?

Graphics.java:

```
import android.graphics.Paint;

public interface Graphics {
    public static enum ImageFormat {
        ARGB8888, ARGB4444, RGB565
    }

    public Image newImage(String fileName, ImageFormat format);

    public void clearScreen(int color);

    public void drawLine(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, int color);

    public void drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int color);

    public void drawImage(Image image, int x, int y, int srcX, int srcY,
            int srcWidth, int srcHeight);

    public void drawImage(Image Image, int x, int y);

    void drawString(String text, int x, int y, Paint paint);

    public int getWidth();

    public int getHeight();

    public void drawARGB(int i, int j, int k, int l);

}
```

AndroidGraphics.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;

import com.n.framework.Graphics;
import com.n.framework.Image;

public class AndroidGraphics implements Graphics {
    AssetManager assets;
    Bitmap frameBuffer;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    Rect srcRect = new Rect();
    Rect dstRect = new Rect();

    public AndroidGraphics(AssetManager assets, Bitmap frameBuffer) {
        this.assets = assets;
        this.frameBuffer = frameBuffer;
        this.canvas = new Canvas(frameBuffer);
        this.paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public Image newImage(String fileName, ImageFormat format) {
        Config config = null;
        if (format == ImageFormat.RGB565)
            config = Config.RGB_565;
        else if (format == ImageFormat.ARGB4444)
            config = Config.ARGB_4444;
        else
            config = Config.ARGB_8888;

        Options options = new Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = config;


        InputStream in = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            in = assets.open(fileName);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            if (bitmap == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                        + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                    + fileName + "'");
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.RGB_565)
            format = ImageFormat.RGB565;
        else if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.ARGB_4444)
            format = ImageFormat.ARGB4444;
        else
            format = ImageFormat.ARGB8888;

        return new AndroidImage(bitmap, format);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearScreen(int color) {
        canvas.drawRGB((color & 0xff0000) >> 16, (color & 0xff00) >> 8,
                (color & 0xff));
    }


    @Override
    public void drawLine(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width - 1, y + height - 1, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
       canvas.drawARGB(a, r, g, b);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawString(String text, int x, int y, Paint paint){
        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);


    }


    public void drawImage(Image Image, int x, int y, int srcX, int srcY,
            int srcWidth, int srcHeight) {
        srcRect.left = srcX;
        srcRect.top = srcY;
        srcRect.right = srcX + srcWidth;
        srcRect.bottom = srcY + srcHeight;


        dstRect.left = x;
        dstRect.top = y;
        dstRect.right = x + srcWidth;
        dstRect.bottom = y + srcHeight;

        canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage) Image).bitmap, srcRect, dstRect,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawImage(Image Image, int x, int y) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage)Image).bitmap, x, y, null);
    }

    public void drawScaledImage(Image Image, int x, int y, int width, int height, int srcX, int srcY, int srcWidth, int srcHeight){


     srcRect.left = srcX;
        srcRect.top = srcY;
        srcRect.right = srcX + srcWidth;
        srcRect.bottom = srcY + srcHeight;


        dstRect.left = x;
        dstRect.top = y;
        dstRect.right = x + width;
        dstRect.bottom = y + height;



        canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage) Image).bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, null);

    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        return frameBuffer.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return frameBuffer.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: ARGB8888 will actually give you the original unaltered pixel material of your graphics including alpha channel. That's of course the most wasteful option but should give you the best image quality and nothing worse than RGB565. What is your "graphics" class? Maybe it does some encoding magic under the hood.

Comment: For me ARGB8888 looks worst. I updated question.

Comment: The following factors come to my mind: your "frameBuffer" bitmap has a different pixel format than ARGB8888 (not sure if this is possible. I believe a mutable bitmap must be ARGB8888), the window's surface on which your graphics are rendered has a different pixel format. Or it may be a scaling artifact when drawing the bitmap on the canvas (drawImage method), because you do not specify a Paint object that enables filtering.

Comment: what is this???? ((AndroidImage) Image).bitmap, x, y, null),,,,, it's not resolved

Comment: Here is answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758198/android-bitmap-memory-question-argb-4444-vs-rgb-565